# undefined reference to `amBXCreateInterface'

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm trying to get this code to work (some old wallwasher lights, so no customer support):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib> //system()
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "IamBX.h"
#include "IamBX_Light.h"

int main()
{
    // Setup amBX Interface and Device Interfaces
    IamBX* pIamBX;
    IamBX_Light *apIamBXLight[9]; // Create lib instance (struct)

    amBXCreateInterface(&pIamBX, 1, 0, "test", "test", NULL, 0);

    // ...
```

but I get

```
undefined reference to `amBXCreateInterface'
```

I have all these files in the working dir:

[image: Directory Listing]

Dependency Walker:

[image: Dependency Walker on ambxrt.dll]

**NOTE**: `amBXCreateInterface` is a function from ambxrt.dll, I just don't know how to use it and Google didn't end up being of much use.

**NOTE 2**: I'm building it using MinGW's g++, tried the `-lm` flag but it gives the same output

Comment: Do you have a ambxrt.lib somewhere? If yes, you must pass this file to your linker. Just having ambxrt.dll in your source dir isn't enough.

Comment: @m88, yes, I have it in the working directory (see screenshot). I don't know how to use linker, I'm a nodeJS guy. Can you help me out here?

Comment: You already linked to `m` by doing `-lm` so it's the same thing: `-lambxrt`. And possibly `-L/path/to/your/libs`

Comment: @m88 can that path be relative? e.g. `-l./lib`

Comment: Either way, it gives the same error, this is how my flags look like: https://prnt.sc/10b7uc8

Comment: I don't see `-lambxrt` and whatever's after that `-L` doesn't look like a valid path (-L specifies a DIR path where the linker will look for (lib)SOMETHING(.dll|.lib) specified by `-lSOMETHING`.

Comment: Corrected to [this](https://pasteboard.co/JQJJT5e.png), now i have `cannot find -lambxrt` as output

Comment: `-L"C:/Path/To/Your/Dir"`

Comment: same error. it seems like the error comes from the `-l` flag, rather than the `-L` one

Comment: The `-l` fails because you're probably screwing up your `-L` argument. Or it doesn't contain your .lib (not just your .dll).

Comment: - Removed spaces from dir, replaced with underscores

- Tried both .dll and .lib, both directories are valid

Comment: What do you mean "both directories"? They should both be in the same directory, the one after `-L`. And their name should be the same except for their extension. And this name is  what should be given after `-l`.

Comment: they are both in the same directory. I meant both files (dll and lib). Also their name is equal, just extension changes

Comment: Well, maybe `ambxrt.lib` doesn't export the symbol you need then. Ask whoever compiled it if they have a minimal working example with MinGW. Can't really help beyond that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an obsolete 2007 library. It's the API for their hardware, yet the company no longer provides support for this